# Html: play audio without controls?

Tags: html, audio

I need to play a mp3 audio file when the user clicks on a image. I only want to audio to play, i.e. there should be no controls, widgets, etc. Nor should the browser launch an external application.

**Edit: ok, I might be able to try out flash. recommendations for a lightweight flash player?**

Comment: bgsound! http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/sounds/_BGSOUND.html

Comment: Sorry there is no way that you can play an audio file in straight HTML.

Comment: Back from the good old days when HTML was all caps :)

Comment: You have to allow a media player of SOME sort to be embedded.  I doubt you are going to see audio playback in the HTML 5 spec as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<embed src="blah.wav" autostart=false loop=false>
```

... but playing sound without flash is evil and will lead to issues cross browser even if there is some [solutions](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm).

You could also use HTML5 and the [audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) tag:

```
<audio src="horse.ogg" controls="controls">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

... but this won't be supported by all browsers.

EDIT: For a flash player you could use [this one](http://www.tsplayer.com/) or [this very simple one](http://flash-mp3-player.net/)... there are tons! Try out examples and see what's best for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. the flash audio players are, however, too complex. i need a very basic flash script that can be launched using javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Now there's a way to do it. Put this: `<audio src="sounds/game-welcome.mp3" style="display:none;" autoplay>` (Replace sounds/game-welcome.mp3 with your file)

Comment: Amazing! Works very well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can still benefit from these, but [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) and jPlayer are two easy to use audio  players. Both are instantiated using JavaScript, call a Flash file behind the scenes, and can be styled using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Let me correct this. With HTML5 .ogg file will play in FireFox only. Adding ***Controls*** element will display controls, to hide controls simply do not add controls element, but again it will only work in FireFox with .ogg file. FireFox does not support MP3 files in HTML5, only Chrome and Safari so far, may be IE9 will later. Your best bet is Flash. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

controls="false"

it's a boolean value