# Wordpress plugin table with audio

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to have a table of information on wordpress which can also play audio? if so, please let me know what type of plugins i can use.

i have looked into Ninja tables but im not sure if it can play audio

For example,

when a user click on the information, it should play an audio.

Comment: So you want a table which a cell has a URL link to a media file in the browser?

Comment: yes, it needs to play. so itll be like selecting a song from a list and it playing in the same broswer and tab

Comment: In the simplest case, Wordpress allows you to upload audio, see https://en.support.wordpress.com/audio/ . In your ninja table, then just add links to the media you uploaded. Simple HTML audio controls see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866376/html-play-audio-without-controls?rq=1 . Why do you think you need to write a custom plugin to handle this?

Comment: What if i wanted to click on some text and play the media.. would that work too ?
for example, if i wanted to create a table of spanish verbs - user clicks on the verbs and media plays